# Checkbox - Compare Values From Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare values and show the output after making the selection on `checkbox`? I am using **jQuery** to do it. After selection had been made, it will not show the output. It will just show for first click only. Then, if we click again, the output will not be changed. Below is my code written so far,

**jQuery**

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
        var $box = $(this),
        $price = $( "input[name='price_range']:checked").val(),
        $nama_pemohon = "<?php echo $nama_pemohon; ?>", 
        $submited_id = <?php echo $submited_id; ?>,
        $jawatan_pemohon = "<?php echo $jawatan_pemohon; ?>",
        $jabatan_pemohon = "<?php echo $jabatan_pemohon; ?>",
        $submited_by = <?php echo $submited_by; ?>,
        $nama = "<?php echo $nama; ?>",
        $jawatan = "<?php echo $jawatan; ?>",
        $jabatan = "<?php echo $jabatan; ?>";

        if($price == "< RM 10,000"){
            $("#submited_by option").val($submited_by).text($nama);
            $("#jawatan_pemohon").text($jawatan);
            $("#jabatan_pemohon").text($jabatan);
        } else {
            $("#submited_by option").val($submited_id).text($nama_pemohon);
            $("#jawatan_pemohon").text($jawatan_pemohon);
            $("#jabatan_pemohon").text($jabatan_pemohon);
        } 

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="< RM 10,000" class="checker"> < RM 10,000.00
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="< RM 200,000" class="checker"> < RM 200,000.00

<select name="submited_by" id="submited_by">
  <option value="<?php echo $submited_by; ?>"><?php echo $nama;?></option>  
</select>
```

Comment: It would be more clear, if you replaced php segments with some constants.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxLvkjzd/), you get change on every click on first checkbox, but only first time on second checkbox.

This is because of your logic in:

```
if($price == "< RM 10,000"){
    $("#submited_by option").val($submited_by).text($nama);
    $("#jawatan_pemohon").text($jawatan);
    $("#jabatan_pemohon").text($jabatan);
} else {
    $("#submited_by option").val($submited_id).text($nama_pemohon);
    $("#jawatan_pemohon").text($jawatan_pemohon);
    $("#jabatan_pemohon").text($jabatan_pemohon);
}
```

Example a:

1. click on first checkbox -> option changes to "nama", because it comes into `if`.
2. click on any checkbox -> option changes to "pemohon", because it comes into `else`.

Example b:

1. click on second checkbox -> option changes to "pemohon", because it comes into `else`.
2. click on second checkbox again -> option doesn't change, because it comes into `else` again.

Comment: Do I need to change the logic or am I missing any function?

Comment: Depends on what you expect from your code. If you need to clear value when you uncheck the checkbox, you should set cleared value inside `else` and set value for second checkbox in `else if`. Are you sure, that checkbox is right idea? Maybe radio button is better option for you.

Comment: If I use eg: `$("input:checkbox").prop('checked',false)` on the `else` statement, will it clear the value?

Comment: It will clear the value of checkbox not value of option from select.

Comment: should I use `empty()` ? Do you have some example or reference for me to check

Comment: I reduced your code a little bit. Maybe you see here, what I meant. https://jsfiddle.net/ybhw8uLx/

Comment: thanks for the help @smjak. May I know if I can make it to click just once. Eg, If I click on `nama`, then, I click on on `pemohon`, it will changed the output to `pemohon` without having to uncheck on `nama`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create a "global" variable outside of your jQuery function.

```
var clicked = false;
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
     if(!clicked) {
        var $box = $(this),
        $price = $( "input[name='price_range']:checked").val(),
        $nama_pemohon = "<?php echo $nama_pemohon; ?>", 
        $submited_id = <?php echo $submited_id; ?>,
        $jawatan_pemohon = "<?php echo $jawatan_pemohon; ?>",
        $jabatan_pemohon = "<?php echo $jabatan_pemohon; ?>",
        $submited_by = <?php echo $submited_by; ?>,
        $nama = "<?php echo $nama; ?>",
        $jawatan = "<?php echo $jawatan; ?>",
        $jabatan = "<?php echo $jabatan; ?>";

        if($price == "< RM 10,000"){
            $("#submited_by option").val($submited_by).text($nama);
            $("#jawatan_pemohon").text($jawatan);
            $("#jabatan_pemohon").text($jabatan);
        } else {
            $("#submited_by option").val($submited_id).text($nama_pemohon);
            $("#jawatan_pemohon").text($jawatan_pemohon);
            $("#jabatan_pemohon").text($jabatan_pemohon);
        } 
        clicked = true;
    }
});
```